# Pickle file to graphML

Tags: python, network-programming, graphml

I am trying to visualise large graphs in [Gephi](https://gephi.org/features/) and am unsure which format is best to save my graph as. At the moment I am simply creating a pickle file as

```
with open('stochastic.pickle', 'rb') as handle:
    sto = pickle.load(handle)
```

However, this format is not supported by Gephi. Having looked through their supported formats I think a graphML format is most versatile.

How can I convert my pickle file to a graphML format?

Comment: If ` sto` was of type `Gephi` use `Gephi` save to method.